# Lookup function for reporting services (visual studios 2008)

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, reporting, reporting-services

I am currently building a report that requires two datasets and two data sources. I am trying to combine the two data sets together with a common field.

My two data sets are: DSSES (tied to SESSQL source) and DSQQST (tied to QQST source)

My DSSES has employee ID field and my DSQQST has Employee_ID field as well. I want to use these two fields too compare the two data sets. Basically the purpose of this report is too find if an employee has changed his or her name. I want to use the lookup function to compare the two employee ID fields and then produce a list of the first name and last name in each data set to produce an answer.

Here are all of the fields of my two datasets:

DSSES:
EmployeeID
EmploymentStatusCode
LastName
FirstName
PreferredName
EmployeeType

DSQQST:
Employee_id
company_id
employeeid
firstname
middlename
lastname
supervisor_id
active_yn
department_id
hire_dt
sup_dept_id
term
terminationDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table with five columns linked to the DSSES dataset. Show the `EmployeeID`, `FirstName` and `LastName` fields. In the fourth column, put the following formula:

```
=Lookup(Fields!EmployeeID.Value, Fields!Employee_id.Value, Fields!firstname.Value, "DSQQST")
```

and similar for the LastName in the fifth column.

Now change the `Visibility`-`Hidden` expression to be:

```
=IIF((Fields!LastName.Value = Lookup(Fields!EmployeeID.Value, Fields!Employee_id.Value, Fields!lastname.Value, "DSQQST")) AND (Fields!FirstName.Value = Lookup(Fields!EmployeeID.Value, Fields!Employee_id.Value, Fields!firstname.Value, "DSQQST")), True, False)
```

So basically show matching results from each dataset and hide the ones where the first names and last names match, thereby only displaying those that are different.

Comment: hi am using VS 2014 but am getting following error on RDLC. i try to use Lookup function (to combine two datasets) in RDLC but it showing below error

Error : [BC30451] 'Lookup' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level